Need suggestions on neural network framework for mapping spatial polygon data to an output metric
I am working on exploring neural networks to create a model for a specific problem: I have a 3D spatial input which is defined by rectangular polygons (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, zcenter). For each polygon, I can apply a load (Load). This load will result in the output metric - say temperature - for each of these polygons. A high load on a given polygon will result in high temperature for that polygon and some lower temperature in neighboring polygons due to heat spreading. I have training data for this behavior which is obtained from physics based solvers.
To simplify, my input and output looks like below:
Input: [N x 6] [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, zcenter, Load] where N is number of polygons.
Output: [N x 1] [Temperature]
I tried few frameworks like 1D CNN, 1D CNN with attention block, 2D CNN (all with some fully connected layers). I performed convolution operation (both 1D and 2D scenarios) on the Nx6 input. None of them seem to capture the spatial behavior I am hoping to capture - Hotspot where there is load and dissipating heat as we go away from hotspot.
Can you please suggest some pointers on what you think would be a good NN framework to address above problem ?
